# Llamada a función JQuery desde PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

pues la pregunta basicamente es el título, ¿Cómo llamo a una función de JQuery dentro de un PHP? He probado varias cosas de internet pero no se por qué no me funcionan. A continuación pongo el codigo importante.

La parte donde hago la llamada:

```
  </head>
    <body>
     <?php 
       include("header.html");    
      if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'] )){
     ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      menu();
    </script>
   <?php
      }
   ?>
```

La parte donde creo el script:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function menu(){
      $('#home').removeClass('active');
      $('#contacto').addClass('active');
      $('#perfil').css({'display':'inline'});
      $('#cerrar').css({'display':'inline'});
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, no se porque la función jquery nunca se llamaba, la manera de solucionarla fue bastante fácil, cree una variable booleana y si la condición se cumplia se llamaba la función en el script y si no no.

```
include("header.html");

 if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'] )){
  $existe = true;
 }
 ?>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function menu(){
      $('#home').removeClass('active');
      $('#contacto').addClass('active');
      $('#perfil').css({'display':'inline'});
      $('#cerrar').css({'display':'inline'});
    }
    var existe = '<?php echo $existe;?>';
    if (existe){
      menu();
    }
  </script>
```